# Unable to set 1440x900 resolution to external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

Today I connected an external monitor whose native resolution is 1440x900. However, my Mac (Retina 13) doesn't allow me to set this resolution. I already tried pressing the Option Key the same time I click on "scaled" inside Display preferences, and, even though many other new resolutions are displayed, mine is not. Is it impossible to set 1440x900 to the external monitor?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the monitor to a different device? It should be possible without any problem. Alternatively you could try a tool like SwitchResX to set the resolution.

Comment: Yes, I tried with a PC and it displays the 1440x900 resolution. I also checked out SwitchResX but I don't really want to pay for it hehe. Thanks.

Comment: Try Display Menu (get it in Mac App Store) - it's free.

Comment: However, my favorite is Retina Display Menu. Read about it here (download link included): https://roaringapps.com/app/rdm-retina-display-menu